# Volley error.ParseError Response Return

Tags: php, android, json, android-volley

Very simple json being called and parsed but no matter what I try I get the following

> com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value $items of
>   type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

The following json is created in a PHP script. When called thru a Volley request, the script loads the json, manipulates a couple of fields, then saves it back to the file.

The json

```
$items=array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'first' => 'Tom',
    'last' => 'Sawyer',
    'email' => 'u@gmail.com',
    'phone' => '1112223344',
    'zip' => '11122',
    'status' => '3',
    ),
);
$unObiect->items = $items;
$json = json_encode($unObiect);
echo($json);
```

The json is created and saved thru

```
$data[]=array(
   'first'=>$temp[0]['first'],
   'last'=>$temp[0]['last'],
   'phone'=>$temp[0]['phone'],
   'email'=>$temp[0]['email'],
   'zip'=>$temp[0]['zip'],
 );
file_put_contents($filename,  '$items=', FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents($filename,  var_export($data,true) . ';'."\n", FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents($filename,  '$unObiect->items = $items;'."\n", FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents($filename,  '$json = json_encode($unObiect);'."\n", FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents($filename,  'echo($json);'."\n", FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents($filename,  '?>', FILE_APPEND);
```

Volley request

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, dataurl, new Response.Listener <JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        if (response != null) {
              try {

                userArray = response.getJSONArray("items");
                for (int i = 0; i < userArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject tempObj = userArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    UserData userData = new UserData();
                    userData.setFirst_name(tempObj.getString("first"));
                    userData.setLast_name(tempObj.getString("last"));
                    userData.setUser_phone(tempObj.getString("phone"));
                    userData.setEmail(tempObj.getString("email"));
                    userData.setTrialdays(tempObj.getString("day"));
                    userData.setStatus(tempObj.getString("status"));
                    userList.add(userData);
                   }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
   Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "No Registration. . ." + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        checkBox();
    }
});
```

I have a feeling it has something to do with the way the json is saved back after modification but I can't pin point it mostly because I am using a second json file with different info created in the same way in a second volley request and receive no errors, loads perfect. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: post your json response..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `content-type` to `application/json` in the header for your GET request. Override the `getHeaders` function while creating the request. Here's a java example.

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(url, jsonBody,
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d("TAG", response.toString());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("TAG", error.getMessage(), error);
        }
    }){

    @Override 
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError { 
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();                
        params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        return params; 
    } 
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I had seen this suggestion previously and simply over looked it as it pertaining to my situation. Not sure why makes perfect sense.

Comment: Great to know that helped.